# Как остановить компиляцию?

Tags: linux, gcc

Как остановить компиляцию (если это вообще компиляция,а не что-то другое) в консоли    Linux(Ubuntu) при использовании GCC?

Comment: ```ctrl+c``` ???

Comment: Я рекомендую удалить вопрос т.к кто-то может расценить его как "глупый" (хотя это необъективно) и заминусовать. В принципе от этого вопроса нет большой пользы сообществу. Вот на тему вам еще ссылка:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)

Comment: Может, имеется в виду `#error`?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, скорее следует закрыть его как неоднозначно сформулированный (см. комментарий от eanmos).

Answer (score 2):

gcc это коллекция компиляторов

> Изначально названный GNU C Compiler поддерживал только язык Си.
>   Позднее GCC был расширен для компиляции исходных кодов на таких языках
>   программирования, как C++, Objective-C, Java, Фортран, Ada, Go, GAS и
>   D.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello");
return(0);
}
```

Компилируем `gcc hello.c -o hello`

Получаем исполнимый файл. Для запуска вызываем его из текущей директории `./hello`

работу gcc можно остановить так же как и работу любого процесса

1. gcc запущен и работает

> Нажатие Ctrl + C заставляет терминал послать сигнал SIGINT процессу,
>   который на данный момент его контролирует. Когда foreground-программа
>   получает сигнал SIGINT, она обязана прервать свою работу.

2. gcc запущен и работает

> Комбинация клавиш Ctrl + Z посылает процессу сигнал, который
>   приказывает ему остановиться. Это значит, что процесс остается в
>   системе, но как бы замораживается.

3. gcc выполняется в фоне

   kill -s KILL gccPS_id

Узнать gcc process id => `ps -aux | grep gcc`

Comment: `pkill gcc` ещё проще. Грохнет все процессы начинающиеся на gcc